# Passing byte-array from java to javascript in React-native bridge

Tags: react-native

I am trying to pass a bytearray object through Promise to the Javascript in react - native.

**Code:**

```
  RawRequest request = new RawRequest(Request.Method.GET, path, new 


 ResponseListener<byte[]>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(byte[] bytes) {

           //Let's pass the response in the form of bytes
             promise.resolve(bytes);

    Log.d(TAG,"The response in bytes length is " + bytes.length);
        }

    }, new ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onError(HttpError httpError) {

        }
    })
```

**Exception:**

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.listviewdbproject, PID: 5965
                                                                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot convert argument of type class [B
                                                                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.Arguments.fromJavaArgs(Arguments.java:57)
                                                                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.CallbackImpl.invoke(CallbackImpl.java:29)
                                                                         at com.facebook.react.bridge.PromiseImpl.resolve(PromiseImpl.java:32)
                                                                         at com.example.creosdk.HttpModule$1.onResponse(HttpModule.java:80)
                                                                         at com.example.creosdk.HttpModule$1.onResponse(HttpModule.java:76)
                                                                         at com.creo.fuel.uttp.http.toolbox.RawRequest.deliverResponse(RawRequest.java:46)
                                                                         at com.creo.fuel.uttp.http.toolbox.RawRequest.deliverResponse(RawRequest.java:16)
                                                                         at com.creo.fuel.uttp.http.delivery.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:100)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5616)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)

Comment: Could you try and send it encoded as a base64 string? The bridge only allows you to pass objects that have a JS equivalent type.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it ? I want to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly resolve Array and ArrayList data structures. React Native specifically provides `WritableNativeArray` to accomplish this. As far as I know it isn't documented anywhere yet but you can find it [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/bridge/WritableNativeArray.java).
The following code works for me, you can extend it to fit your requirements:

```
@ReactMethod
public void sendArrays(Promise promise) {

    WritableArray arr = new WritableNativeArray();

    arr.pushString("hello");
    arr.pushString("world");

    promise.resolve(arr);
}
```

And on the JS side:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { someNativeModule } = NativeModules;

const getArrays = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await someNativeModule.sendArrays();

    return response;
    } catch (err) {
    // handle errors
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is late by years, but I had a similar issue. My solution was to create in React-Native an array of strings that had the byte value therein; ie ["52", "0"] and in the native portion, turn that back into a byte array.

I originally attempted this using strings, but the React-Native to Java bridge trims trailing null codes from strings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement and ended up converting the ByteArray to a base64 string.  In Kotlin:

```
String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(myByteArray))
```

You can send this string over the bridge to your JavaScript the same way you would any other string and convert it to a JS Buffer:

```
const myBuffer = Buffer.from(myByteString, 'base64');
```